# Cantor's intersection theorem for metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

A nest is a family of sets totally ordered by inclusion.

> Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space and $\mathcal{N}$ a nest of nonempty closed subsets of $X$ such that $\inf_{A\in\mathcal{N}}\operatorname{diam}A=0$. Then $\bigcap\mathcal{N}$ is a singleton.

I can prove this theorem when $\mathcal{N}$ is a sequence. Simply take a point from each set and this constitutes a Cauchy sequence. For a nest I think this works: Let $(C_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}\subseteq\mathcal{N}$ such that $C_{n+1}\subseteq C_n$ for all $n$ and that $\lim\operatorname{diam}C_n=0$. By the case for sequences, we have $\bigcap C_n=\{z\}$ for some $z\in X$. For each $C\in\mathcal{N}$, since $\operatorname{diam}C>0$,* there is some $k$ with $\operatorname{diam}C_k<\operatorname{diam}C$. Since either $C\subseteq C_k$ or $C_k\subseteq C$, it must be the latter case, therefore $z\in C_k\subseteq C$ and $z\in\bigcap\mathcal{N}$.

Is my proof correct?

Edit: *If $\operatorname{diam}⁡C=0$, then $C$ must be a singleton, since the distance between two distinct points must $>0$. Suppose $C=\{z\}$. Then since the sets in $\mathcal{N}$ are nonemtpy, for each $D\in\mathcal{N}$ we must have $C\subseteq D$, and $z\in\bigcap\mathcal{N}$.

Comment: Why is the diameter of $C$ greater than $0$?

Comment: If $\operatorname{diam}C=0$, then $C$ must be a singleton, since the distance between two distinct points must $>0$. Suppose $C=\{z\}$. Then since the sets in $\mathcal{N}$ are nonemtpy, for each $D\in\mathcal{N}$ we must have $C\subseteq D$, and $z\in\bigcap\mathcal{N}$.

Comment: Your definition of a nest is "a family of sets linearly ordered by inclusion"?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes. It means for each $A,B\in\mathcal{N}$, either $A\subseteq B$ or $B\subseteq A$.

Comment: @Colescu: OK, you still need to explain this because it is not a priori clear that the diameter of $C$ is zero.

Comment: @max_zorn Thanks. I'll edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\diam}{\operatorname{diam}}$
Yes, the idea is correct. The sequence part you should write out as a lemma of sorts maybe (it's in fact the original statement by Cantor) and reduce the nest case to a sequence:

**fact** We can assume WLOG that all $\diam(C) > 0$ for all $C \in \mathcal{N}$:
If $\diam(C) = 0$ then $C = \{p\}$ for some $p \in X$. But as we have a nest we automatically have that $\{p\} = \bigcap \mathcal{N}$ (as every $C$ either contains $\{p\}$ is is contained in it, and there are no empty subsets, so the former must be the case).

By recursion we go on: pick $C_0\in \mathcal{N} $ with $0< \diam(C_0) < 1$ which can be done as $\inf_{A \in \mathcal{N}} \diam(A) = 0$. Having picked $C_n \in \mathcal{N}$ we pick $C_{n+1} \in \mathcal{N}$ such that $\diam(C_{n+1}) < \min(\diam(C_n), \frac{1}{n})$, which can also be done as the right hand side is some real $>0$. The fact that $\diam(C_{n+1}) < \diam(C_n)$ and we have a nest forces $C_{n+1} \subset C_n$ (as $\emptyset \neq A \subseteq B$ always implies $\diam(A) \le \diam(B)$).

By the sequence version we then conclude that thare is a unique $p \in X$ such that $\{p\} = \bigcap_n C_n \supseteq \bigcap \mathcal{N}$. Then your final argument will show that indeed $p \in C$ for any $C \in \mathcal{N}$, because we can find $C_n$ with $\diam(C_n) < \frac{1}{n} < \diam(C)$ for some $n$ and the nestedness forces $C_n \subset C$ again and thus $p \in C$.

So your argument is esentially correct, but the non-zero diameter fact should maybe be more explicit and the reduction to a sequence also formalised with a recursion argument. It depends on the level of rigour and background of this class, I suppose, how much you'd need to do it. In my old university this was the level of detail we were asked to provide.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I was just typing this post when the proof occurred to me, so I only wrote a sketch. :)